# Problem concerning the limits of composition of functions.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove the following proposition.

[image]

However I cant seemt to understand How the presented hint is relevant. Please provide some more clarification concerning this hint, though if you cannot do so without giving away the solution then please say so as well.

Comment: I would not expect  this hint to be helpful in the proof. Have you tried showing the result?

Comment: @AnyAD No, i have not yet tried to prove the result i stopped upon looking at the hint, all i really wanted to know is Why does the point need to be made at all?

Comment: To me the hint seems to imply that the the sequence $f (x)$ may 'attain' its limit eventually. This would imply that $c_2$ is an element of $B $. In this case $g (c_2)=L$.